# multiple sides of object selected

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've been following blenderguru's tutorial on Blender 3.0, and I've gotten to part 4 (video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1isb0x4zYw&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=4). At around 10:00, he is talking about using the 'g' key to stretch the mesh (I've tried following every exact movement he makes), but when I use the 'g' key, it selects multiple sides of the icing. [image: my icing, with the donut hidden] How can this problem be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have X-Ray mode toggled on.
You can simply fix this by pressing "Alt + z" or just click the icon shown in the Image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on this for so long